# Как вывести дату и время в textVIew.

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, дата, время

Здравствуете вот задался вопросом как как красиво и немаловажно правильно  вывести дату и время в textView ,все прошлые попытки увенчались провалом(Заранее благодарю за помощь)

Comment: Добавьте код, который получился в результате прошлых попыток.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm, dd-EEEE-yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
textView.setText(date);
```

Comment: Спасибо)) У меня последний вопрос, У меня имеется listview , и при переходе из объекта листвью  приложение вылетает  ,без  этого кода с датой и времени все работает ) Как вы думаете почему это происходит?

Comment: Причин может быть почти бесконечное количество. Но, раз вы не приводите логи или зотя бы тип ошибки, то это с 95% вероятностью указывает, помимо прочего, на то, что у вас NPE, а именно `textView` у вас `null`, но это не точно.

Comment: Ошибок не выдает.Вот исходники  https://yadi.sk/d/ljCaMMDR3JG699,  если получиться объяснить что не так такому дуболому как я ,то я буду искренне благодарен.

Comment: @ДанилаШувалов, по ссылкам не хожу. Вам проще создать новый вопрос, выложить в него проблемный код текстом, логи ошибки и указать строку возникновения.